# mysql get user rank using inner join

Tags: mysql

I have three tables as following. And i want to get user with highest rank.

1) users table as

```
id        | user_id  | created_at
1         | 100      |   2014-11-07 02:54:09
2         | 102      |   2014-11-08 03:52:40
3         | 103      |   2014-11-10 02:47:26
4         | 104      |   2014-11-11 02:54:48
5         | 105      |   2014-11-14 03:11:23
6         | 105      |   2014-11-15 00:56:34
```

2) user_profile table as

```
id        | user_id  | rank
1         | 100      |   100
2         | 102      |   500
3         | 103      |   10
4         | 104      |   0
5         | 105      |   11
6         | 105      |   1000
```

3) user_followers table as

```
id        | user_id  | followers
1         | 100      |   10
2         | 102      |   20
3         | 103      |   30
4         | 104      |   40
5         | 105      |   0
6         | 105      |   50
```

Now my query is i want to get list of users short by highest rank in table2. In case of tie user with the highest followers in table3 will win. In case of same followers user who is created first will win.

And another one i want to find user rank with same logic passing by user id.

I already tried something like

```
SET @i=0;
SELECT user_id, rank, @i:=@i+1 AS rank FROM user_profile ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Show us your SQL.

Comment: I edited what i already tried but not getting with inner join. Need  help.

Comment: I don't know why @Arion's answer was deleted. It was almost there

Comment: @Arion can you pleaas put back your answer?

Comment: The bit you haven't explained is how to handle users with multiple profiles/followers - like 105

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT
 @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, *
FROM
(
SELECT users.user_id, user_profile.rank, user_followers.followers, users.created_at
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_profile ON users.user_id = user_profile.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_followers ON users.user_id = user_followers.user_id
ORDER BY user_profile.rank DESC, user_followers.followers DESC, users.created_at ASC
)
```

Comment: You're missing the whole "in case of tie" part of the question.

Comment: This will return the list of user. But i want to give 1st rank to the user who have highest rank or followers

Comment: Hardik, added the rank.

Answer (score 0):

Arion's answer looked like this...

```
SELECT
users.*
FROM
users
JOIN user_profile
    ON users.user_id = user_profile.user_id
JOIN user_followers
    ON user_profile.user_id=user_followers.user_id
ORDER BY
user_profile.rank DESC,
user_followers.followers DESC,
users.created_at DESC
```

...but this seems a little closer to what you're after...

```
 SELECT u.user_id
      , u.created_at
      , up.rank
      , uf.followers 
      , @i:=@i+1 corrected_rank
   FROM users u 
   LEFT 
   JOIN user_profile up 
     ON up.user_id = u.user_id 
   LEFT 
   JOIN user_followers uf 
     ON uf.user_id = u.user_id
  CROSS
   JOIN (SELECT @i:=1) v
  ORDER
     BY rank DESC
      , followers DESC
      , created_at ASC;
```

Comment: Yes this is closer to my query. can you please help me to find specific user rank? Like if i have rank 100(highest) and followers 100(highest) than my rank is first.